# React html validation

Tags: html, reactjs, validation

I try to use the onInvalid on my fields for the validation of form to change the message. Except that it writes me [object: Object]

```
<CustomInputValidation
                  labelText={<FormattedMessage id="LoginTemplate.email" defaultMessage="Email"/>}
                  id="email"
                  formControlProps={{
                    fullWidth: true, 
                    error:errors.email === true ? true : false, required: true,   
                    onInvalid: (e) => e.target.setCustomValidity(<FormattedMessage id="LoginTemplate.email" defaultMessage="Email"/>),
                    onInput: (e) => e.target.setCustomValidity('')
                  }}
                  inputProps={{
                    onChange:this.handleChange,
                    type: "email",
                    name:"email",
                    value:authentification.email,
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    )
                  }}
                  boolError={errors.email === true ? true : false}
                  labelError={<FormattedMessage id="LoginTemplate.email.error" defaultMessage="The email is required"/>}
                />
```

Comment: Are you able to give some more detail, for instance, the library you're using, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: The expected message is: the e-mail is required

Comment: @dna and the library / what you expect to happen?

Comment: I use react, material ui and react-intl